# Different Hibernate save() interpretation

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit, hql

I making my first Spring+Hibernate+PostgreSQL project and faced a strange behavior of the hibernate interpretation of `getCurrentSession().save()`.

Here my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private Long id;
    @Version
    private long version;
    @Column(name = "delivery_date")
    private Date deliveryDate;
    @Column(name = "delivery_time")
    private Time deliveryTime;
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;
    @Column(name = "delivery_address")
    private String deliveryAddress;
    @Column(name = "executor_id")
    private Long executorId;
    private String comment;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<BasketUnit> basketUnitList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "basket")
public class BasketUnit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "unit_id")
    private Long id;
    @Version
    private long version;
    @Column(name = "item_id")
    private Long itemId;
    private int quantity;
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order order;
```

HibernateConfig:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:hibernate.properties"})
public class HibernateConfig {
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    HibernateConfig(Environment environment){
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("io.delivery.entity");
        localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("hibernate.driverClass"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("hibernate.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("hibernate.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("hibernate.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

DAO class:

```
@Transactional
public abstract class BasicDaoImpl<T> implements BasicDao<T> {
    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public BasicDaoImpl(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    @Override
    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }


    @Override
    public T create(T entity) {
        getCurrentSession().save(entity);
        return entity;
    }
```

I have module test for service, where on every test call `create(entity)`.
If I run tests one-by-one all OK, but if I run test class I got `HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1` on any second test.

In the logs I see that Hibernate interprete `save()` in hql at the first run:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        orders
        (comment, delivery_address, delivery_date, delivery_time, executor_id, user_id, version) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        basket
        (item_id, order_id, quantity, version) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

but for the second and others runs :

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        orders
        (comment, delivery_address, delivery_date, delivery_time, executor_id, user_id, version) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    update
        basket 
    set
        item_id=?,
        order_id=?,
        quantity=?,
        version=? 
    where
        unit_id=? 
        and version=?
```

i.e. `update` instead of `insert` which most likely leads to an error.
What could be the reason for this behavior and how to get the `save()` to work properly?

Or maybe the problem is somewhat different?

**UPDATE**

test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class, OrderServiceImpl.class, HibernateConfig.class})
public class OrderServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    private static final int TEST_QUANTITY = 42;
    private static final String TEST_DELIVERY_ADDRESS = "Nowhere";
    private static final String TEST_DELIVERY_COMMENT = "Notext";

    private static List<BasketUnit> basketUnits = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        basketUnits.add(new BasketUnit(20L));
        basketUnits.add(new BasketUnit(21L));
        basketUnits.add(new BasketUnit(22L));
        basketUnits.add(new BasketUnit(23L));
    }

    @Test
    public void updateOrder() {
        Order order = createOrder();
        assertNotNull(order);

        order.setDeliveryAddress(TEST_DELIVERY_ADDRESS);
        order.setComment(TEST_DELIVERY_COMMENT);

        Order updatedOrder = orderService.updateOrder(order);

        assertNotNull(updatedOrder);
        assertEquals(TEST_DELIVERY_ADDRESS, updatedOrder.getDeliveryAddress());
        assertEquals(TEST_DELIVERY_COMMENT, updatedOrder.getComment());
        orderService.deleteOrder(order.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void updateBasketUnit() {

        Order order = createOrder();
        assertNotNull(order);
        assertNotNull(order.getBasketUnitList().get(0));

        order.getBasketUnitList().get(0).setQuantity(TEST_QUANTITY);
        Order updatedOrder = orderService.updateOrder(order);

        assertNotNull(updatedOrder);
        assertNotNull(updatedOrder.getId());
        assertEquals(TEST_QUANTITY, updatedOrder.getBasketUnitList().get(0).getQuantity());
        orderService.deleteOrder(order.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteBasketUnit() {

        Order order = createOrder();
        assertNotNull(order);

        List<BasketUnit> basket = order.getBasketUnitList();
        assertNotNull(basket);
        assertNotNull(basket.get(0));
        long id = basket.get(0).getId();

        orderService.deleteBasketUnitById(id);

        assertNull(orderService.findBasketUnitById(id));
        orderService.deleteOrder(order.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void addBasketUnit() {

        Order order = createOrder();
        assertNotNull(order);

        BasketUnit basketUnitToAdd = new BasketUnit(19L);
        order.addBasketUnit(basketUnitToAdd);
        Order updatedOrder = orderService.updateOrder(order);

        assertThat(updatedOrder.getBasketUnitList(), hasItem(hasProperty("id", is(basketUnitToAdd.getId()))));
        orderService.deleteOrder(order.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void GetByUserId() {

        Order order = createOrder();
        List<Order> ordersByUserId = orderService.findByUserId(order.getUserId());

        assertThat(ordersByUserId, hasItem(hasProperty("id", is(order.getId()))));

        assertNotNull(ordersByUserId);
        orderService.deleteOrder(order.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteOrder() {
        Order order = createOrder();
        assertNotNull(order);

        Order responceOrder = orderService.deleteOrder(order.getId());
        assertNull(orderService.findById(responceOrder.getId()));
    }

    @Test
    public void GetOrderById() {
        Order order = createOrder();

        Order responceOrder = orderService.findById(order.getId());

        assertEquals(order.getId(), responceOrder.getId());
        assertNotNull(responceOrder);
        orderService.deleteOrder(order.getId());
    }

    private Order createOrder() {
        Order order = prefillOrder();
        orderService.create(order);

        assertNotNull(order);
        return order;
    }


    private Order prefillOrder() {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setUserId(135L);
        order.setComment("true comment");
        order.setDeliveryDate(Date.valueOf("1984-01-08"));
        order.setDeliveryTime(Time.valueOf("04:05:06"));
        order.setDeliveryAddress("Moscow");
        order.setExecutorId(350L);
        order.setBasketUnitList(basketUnits);
        return order;
    }
```

Comment: And you include a whole lotta code, but forget the thing that matters, the actual test...

Comment: @M.Deinum Done.

Comment: You are putting the `basketUnits` into the `Order` that gets created for each method. However the entries in that list are only persisted once after that they are persisted and next methods will update them. If the relation is a bi-directional one matters are even worse. So basically your test is flawed.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thx a lot! My big mistake is to try evaulate test Order creation in @Before block, so `static` of test BasketUnits is remnants of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavour is due to `static` state of subordinate table items in test, so Hibernate persist it once in the context.